# REACT - independently displaying an element to a similar element

Tags: reactjs, jsx

**Issue :**
When I click on any **li** element, its containing **DIV element** (dropdown) is being displayed. It works fine however the other dropdowns which are belong to other **li** element is also displayed.

In a react developer tool will be noticed that if I click any **li** element, all dropdown components will be  re-rendered. So I assume that this the main cause why all dropdowns are being displayed instead of only one.

So, basically I want the dropdown in a clicked **li** be displayed and the other dropdown is not affected.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';


export default function Navigation(){
    const Nav_JSON  = [
         { "name" : "Place" , "icon": "fas fa-location-arrow" },
         { "name" : "Online Services" , "href" : "#", "icon": "fas fa-wifi" ,
             "dropdowns" : [
                 {"name" : "link 1" , "href" : "/home.html"},
                 {"name" : "Link 2" , "href" : "/home.html"},
                 {"name" : "link 3" , "href" : "/home.html"}
             ]
         },
         { "name" : "E-mail", "href" : "#", "icon": "fas fa-envelope" }];
     


    const [showDrop, setShowDrop] = useState(false);

    return(
        <div className="navigation-container">
           {Nav_JSON.map((nav , key) => (
               <li  key={key} className="nav-list" onClick={ () => {setShowDrop(!showDrop)}}>
                   <div className="nav-link-container">
                       <a className="nav-link" href={nav.href}> 
                            <i className={nav.icon}></i> { nav.name }
                       </a>
                   </div>
                    <Dropdown dropdowns={nav.dropdowns} showDrop={showDrop} />
                    
               </li>
               
           ))}
        </div>
    )    
}


const Dropdown = ({ dropdowns, showDrop }) => {
    if (dropdowns){
        return (
            <div className="dropdown" style={ showDrop ? display : noDisplay}>
                <div className="dropdown-container">
                    {dropdowns.map((dropdown, key) => (
                        <div key={key} className="dropdown-link">
                            <a className="dropdown-link" href={dropdown.href}>
                                { dropdown.name }
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}


const display = {
    display : "block"
}

const noDisplay = {
    display : "none"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a single state for all dropdowns. Whenever the state changes, all dropdowns react accordingly. Create a Component (`NavItem`) that will have a state for each dropdown.

```
const NavItem = ({ nav }) => {
  const [showDrop, setShowDrop] = useState(false)

  return (
    <li  key={key} className="nav-list" onClick={() => {setShowDrop(!showDrop)}}>
      <div className="nav-link-container">
        <a className="nav-link" href={nav.href}> 
          <i className={nav.icon}></i> { nav.name }
        </a>
      </div>
      <Dropdown dropdowns={nav.dropdowns} showDrop={showDrop} />
    </li>
  )
}


export default function Navigation(){    
  return(
    <div className="navigation-container">
    {Nav_JSON.map(nav => (
      <NavItem nav={nav} key={nav.name} />
    ))}
    </div>
  )    
}
```